# How many chains before the cassette is replaced?

Tags: chain, cassette, wear

If you change your chain at recommended interval (using wear indicator), how many chains should you get through before the cassette is replaced?

Comment: I would say 3-4, if you don't run the chains too long, and if your usage is reasonably "normal".

Answer (score 6):

This is really going to be different for each person. If you replace your chain early enough, there should be very little wear on your cassette and you can go more chains between cassettes. If you let the chain go for a long time, you pretty much have to replace the cassette with the chain.  Each one should be replaced as they are needed depending on wear.  The amount of wear on the cassette is going to depend a lot on your riding style. If you spend a lot of time in one gear, that sprocket is going to wear out. If you use all the gears evenly, the cassette as a whole will last more miles.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head with this being different for every situation and individual.  When the chain and the rest of the drivetrain is maintained well.  When neglected, chain wear and abrasive dirt will accelerate wear on all the drive train.  The other points all add up as well.